# Spring mvc occured an exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to post an xml string to my controller, since there will have different structure xmls to pass in.

But my controller report an error which says cant complete the request, error message is below:

```
Could not complete request
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getStatus()I
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) [catalina.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:617) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1778) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.44]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_112]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getStatus()I
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.checkNotModified(ServletWebRequest.java:220) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.checkNotModified(ServletWebRequest.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:981) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 18 more
```

Here is my web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/spring-config-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And my spring-config-mvc.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

My controller is

```
package com.demo;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class Controller {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
    @ResponseBody
    public String receiveData(@RequestBody String xml) {
        LOGGER.info("done!!!!!!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

There is no log output. Is there something wrong in my config or code?

Comment: Spring 5 requires a Servlet 3.1 container... Tomcat 6 doesn't really qualify for that you need at least 8.5.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you, it works